# SQL Server : Verify a list of text from a table

Tags: sql-server

Could you please help me with a query for the following requirements?

I have a list of Cities which I want to verify from a table. The query will have the Input List (below) in the where clause and gives me results like shown below in expected result.

```
Input list = ('City1','City2','City3','City4',.......'City100')
```

Expected result

```
 1. City1  Exist 
 2. City2  Exist 
 3. City3  Not Exist 
 4. City4  Exist 
 5. City5  Not Exist
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any queries yourself so far to do this?

Comment: I have so far googled and found a lot of how to use 'If Exists', 'Case' statements. But I am not that good with my SQL querying skills.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this: Just paste my code into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs (most important is to replace the "@ExistingCities" with your actual table's name):

First I declare a "table" with some already existing cities (3 and 5 are missing). The input string misses City4.

```
DECLARE @ExistingCities TABLE(CityName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @ExistingCities VALUES('City1'),('City2'),('City4'),('City6');

DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(MAX)='City1,City2,City3,City5,City6';

WITH SplittedInput AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@input,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS CitiesAsXml
)
SELECT oneCity.value('.','varchar(max)') AS InputName
      ,CASE WHEN exC.CityName IS NOT NULL THEN 'Exist' ELSE 'Not Exist' END AS ResultCode
FROM SplittedInput
CROSS APPLY CitiesAsXml.nodes('/x') AS InputCity(oneCity)
LEFT JOIN @ExistingCities AS exC ON exC.CityName=oneCity.value('.','varchar(max)')
```

Comment: @Savql, If my answer helped you, I'd ask you to mark it as accepted (there's a check sign below the vote counter) and upvote it (you need 15 reputation points for upvotes..., so maybe later...). This will on the one hand show up, that this problem is resolved and on the other hand the reputation points will make me happy :-) Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Please check following SQL script,
For demo I created a sql CityList table with sample data

```
create table cityList (id int identity(1,1), city nvarchar(50),)
insert into cityList(city) values ('City1'),('City3')

declare @input nvarchar(max) = 'City1,City2,City3,City4,City100'
select
    s.val,
    case when c.city is not null then 'Exist' else 'Not Exist' end
from dbo.split(@input,',') s
left join cityList c on c.city = s.val
```

Please note that you need the [SQL string Split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) codes for dbo.split() function

I hope it helps

[image]

Comment: Dear Eralper ..It took me a while to understand what to do with the split() function. After that your code snippet executed successfully. Thanks for your help.